# How to break loop of pcap_loop without pcap_breakloop

Tags: c, linux, libpcap

I have libpcap version 0.6 and linux kernel version 2.6.18 in which i cannot upgrade either of these and `pcap_breakloop()` function available from the version 0.8.

My question is how can I break `pcap_loop()`  without using `pcap_breakloop()`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Answer (score 1):

Longer answer: you can't, but what you could try is writing your own loop, using `pcap_dispatch()`, and check a "should I break out of the loop?" flag before each call to `pcap_dispatch()`.

This isn't *as* good, as `pcap_dispatch()` might also loop, and that wouldn't break out of the loop, although, in libpcap 0.6 (which is ***REALLY*** old, BTW - older than the 2.6.18 kernel, as far as I know), it doesn't loop on Linux.